# Do we need to declare states in components after learning react with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have recently completed my react with redux tutorial and now I have a question regarding state of component.

As it is already explained that Redux is a state management library which is used to store all possible states of your react app at one place and reduce the code redundancy to access any particular state in any component.

Now my question is that if we can create and modify any number of states at one place using redux and can access it anywhere in our app (in components obviously) then will it eliminate the need of creating states in particular component and modifying the state in that particular component?

Please explain this and if possible then provide some example also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use Redux to manage state related to the data and also any other information which needs to be accessed from outside the current component.
But you can use component state for things like component specific UI related data.

e.g. the state of a popover / "Read more" section state
 which are not needed to access from out side the component.

But you'll need to let Redux manage data like Selected element of a item list which might need to be accessed from another component.

Comment: Ok so we use redux when we want to send data as props to children components. But if it is for personal use of component then we just use react traditional way to create state. Nice explaination @Lakshitha Ruwan

Answer (score 1):

I still use the state most of the times. For example, if you are using a form, you will not want to create actions, reducers and selectors for every input, checkbox, etc.
Redux is used when you need to access the state from one component in another component that is 'far away'. I would say that for all the rest of the cases, where you just need your state in the actual component, or in one that is parent or children of the component, just go with the traditional state.

Answer (score 0):

> Use React for ephemeral state that doesn't matter to the app globally and doesn't mutate in complex ways

Here is the source and a deeper explanation: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1287